# Затирание участка EEPROM STM32

Tags: c, stm32

Хочу затереть участок c 0x08080000 до 0x08081800 памяти EEPROM на STM32L083, что есть вся память EEPROM.

```
HAL_FLASHEx_DATAEEPROM_Unlock();
__HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG( FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR );
for( uint32_t i = 0x08080000; i < 0x08086000; i += 4 )
{
    *( uint32_t *)i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
HAL_FLASHEx_DATAEEPROM_Lock();
```

Затирает только с 0x08080000 до 0x08081060. И падает по вачдогу.
В чем причина?

Comment: 1. Уточните тип памяти. На STM обычно вся память типа FLASH, а не EEPROM. FLASH-память нельзя стирать просто устанавливая единички во все биты, нужно запустить специальную функцию стирания. 2. Запись памяти - очень долгая операция, поэтому вполне может быть, что время сторожевого таймера на самом деле истекло. Возможно, имеет смысл отключить его на время операций записи памяти.

Comment: Сброс ватчдога помог